# bpopup jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, bpopup

I'm trying to use one of bpopup examples in my xhtml page, and I have tried everything I can think of but it's not working.

bpopup (jQuery plugin),[code example](http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/#Usage)

here is my try so far..

**HTML:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
<title>Calendar</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/style.min.css" media="screen" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/jquery.bpopup-0.9.4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
 <!-- Button that triggers the popup -->
        <button id="#my-button">POP IT UP</button>
        <!-- Element to pop up -->
        <div id="#element_to_pop_up">Content of popup</div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**js:**

```
// Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting
// Encapsulation
// $ is assigned to jQuery
;(function($) {

 // DOM Ready
$(function() {

    // Binding a click event
    // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
    $('#my-button').bind('click', function(e) {

        // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
        e.preventDefault();

        // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
        $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
    content:'iframe', //'ajax', 'iframe' or 'image'
    contentContainer:'.content',
    loadUrl:'http://dinbror.dk/search' //Uses jQuery.load()
});


    });

});

})(jQuery);
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: check if the console is having ajax error.

Comment: No errors, button is working but no action @CerlinBoss

Comment: can you give us any sample demo to play with?

Comment: [link](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/) 5. Example 5a, content: Simple jQuery popup that loads external html page with ajax. (Ajax popup)

Comment: Just overlooking `<button id="#my-button">POP IT UP</button>` the Id `#` has to do something :? and `// From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()` or this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

I just deleted # in button id  and in element_to_pop_up

```
 <!-- Button that triggers the popup -->
        <button id="my-button">POP IT UP</button
        <!-- Element to pop up -->
        <div id="element_to_pop_up"> hello </div>
```

and use this css file instead :

```
 #element_to_pop_up, .bMulti {
background-color: #FFF;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
box-shadow: 0 0 25px 5px #999;
color: #111;
display: none;
min-width: 450px;
min-height: 250px;
padding: 25px;
}

#element_to_pop_up .logo {
color: #2B91AF;
font: bold 325% 'Petrona',sans;
}

.button.b-close, .button.bClose {
border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
box-shadow: none;
font: bold 131% sans-serif;
padding: 0 6px 2px;
position: absolute;
right: -7px;
top: -7px;
 }

.button {
background-color: #2B91AF;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
color: #FFF;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 20px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}
```